# Radio button not edit after clicking on edit button in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, crud

The radio button is not selected after clicking on edit button. Im trying to edit/update data but values are not edited in form.

````
   <div class="form-group col">
      <label>*Gender:-</label>
      <div class="form-group col">
        <input type='radio' name='gender' value='Male'
       // check for male value 
       ```
        <?php
          if(isset($row['gender']) == 'Male') {
              echo "checked";
          }
        ?> ``` >
        <label>Male</label>
        <input type='radio' class='ml-3' name='gender' value='Female' 
        // check for female value 
        ```<?php
          if(isset($row['gender']) == 'Female') {
              echo "checked";
          }
        ?> ```>/* radio value is not edited or selected after clicking on edit button */
        <label>Female</label>
      </div>
    </div>
````

Comment: `isset($row['gender']) == 'Male'` makes no sense. The return value of `isset` is a boolean.

Comment: If I dont use isset then other errors are coming.

Comment: If you need to check if the value is set, before you compare it with a given static string - then do exactly that. `if(isset($row['gender']) && $row['gender'] == 'Male')`

Comment: Thanks, CBroe friend. My code is working now fine. The problem with my code as if I clicked on the edit button only the male value was getting checked. Looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $row['gender'] = 'Male'; ?> //for checking
<?php isset($row['gender']) ? $gender = $row['gender'] : $gender = '' ?> //ternary operator...if you need you can use if..else


       <div class="form-group col">
      <label>*Gender:-</label>
      <div class="form-group col">
        <input type='radio' name='gender' value='Male'
        <?php
        if($gender == 'Male'){ echo "checked"; } else { echo ""; } ?> >
        <label>Male</label>

        <input type='radio' class='ml-3' name='gender' value='Female'
        <?php
        if($gender == 'Female'){ echo "checked"; } else { echo ""; } ?> >
        <label>Female</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```